# Relacionar tablas y mostrar resultados

Tags: php, html, jquery

Es demasiado fácil de responder, ya que simplemente voy a preguntar cómo debería escribir la consulta que presentaré a continuación. Les explico de qué va.
Tengo tablas relacionadas, pero el problema es que no sé cómo mostrar el resultado correspondiente.
Ejemplo de lo que me sucede: tabla "productos" (relacionada con "marcas") producto:cámara marca:2(2=id que contiene la tabla "marcas" = nombre de la marca correspondiente al id).
O sea, en vez de mostrarme el nombre de la marca, solo me muestra el id.
Les dejo mi código.

ajax.js

```
$(obtener_registros());

function obtener_registros(alumnos)
{
    $.ajax({
        url : 'buscando.php',
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'html',
        data : { alumnos: alumnos },
        })

    .done(function(resultado){
        $("#tabla_resultado").html(resultado);
    })
}

$(document).on('keyup', '#busqueda', function()
{
    var valorBusqueda=$(this).val();
    if (valorBusqueda!="")
    {
        obtener_registros(valorBusqueda);
    }
    else
        {
            obtener_registros();
        }
});
```

buscando.php

```
$tabla="";
$query="SELECT * FROM productos ORDER BY id";

///////// LO QUE OCURRE AL TECLEAR SOBRE EL INPUT DE BUSQUEDA ////////////
if(isset($_POST['alumnos']))
{
    $q=$conexion->real_escape_string($_POST['alumnos']);
    $query="SELECT id, descri, precio, marca, catego, pais, imagen FROM productos
    WHERE marca LIKE '%".$q."%' OR catego LIKE '%".$q."%' OR pais LIKE '%".$q."%'";
}

$buscarAlumnos=$conexion->query($query);
if ($buscarAlumnos->num_rows > 0)
{
    $tabla.=
    '<table class="table">
        <tr class="bg-primary">
                               <td>id</td>
                           <td>descri</td>
                           <td>precio</td>
                           <td>marca</td>
                           <td>catego</td>
                           <td>pais</td>
                           <td>imagen</td>
        </tr>';

    while($filaAlumnos= $buscarAlumnos->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $tabla.=
        '<tr>
            <td>'.$filaAlumnos['id'].'</td>
            <td>'.utf8_encode($filaAlumnos['descri']).'</td>
            <td>'.$filaAlumnos['precio'].'</td>
            <td>'.$filaAlumnos['marca'].'</td>
            <td>'.$filaAlumnos['catego'].'</td>
            <td>'.$filaAlumnos['pais'].'</td>
            <td>'.$filaAlumnos['imagen'].'</td>
         </tr>
        ';
    }

    $tabla.='</table>';
```

tablas
Productos

```
CREATE TABLE `productos` (
    `id` INT(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `descri` VARCHAR(316) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    `precio` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    `marca` INT(3) NOT NULL,
    `catego` INT(3) NOT NULL,
    `pais` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    `imagen` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `marca` (`marca`),
    INDEX `catego` (`catego`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_productos_categorias` FOREIGN KEY (`catego`) REFERENCES `categorias` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_productos_marcas` FOREIGN KEY (`marca`) REFERENCES `marcas` (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_spanish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=5;
```

tabla marcas (la tabla categoria es igual a marcas solo que en nombre tiene "nombre_c" en vez de "nombre_m")

```
CREATE TABLE `marcas` (
    `id` INT(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nombre_m` VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_spanish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=6;
```

ACTUAL COMPLETO

```
<?php

$conexion = new mysqli("localhost","root","","minos");


//////////////// VALORES INICIALES ///////////////////////

$tabla="";
$query="SELECT * FROM productos ORDER BY id";

///////// LO QUE OCURRE AL TECLEAR SOBRE EL INPUT DE BUSQUEDA ////////////
if(isset($_POST['alumnos']))
{
    $q=$conexion->real_escape_string($_POST['alumnos']);
    $query=" SELECT
            p.id,
            p.descri,
            p.precio,
            m.nombre_m,
            c.nombre_c,
            p.pais,
            p.imagen
        FROM productos p
        INNER JOIN marcas m     ON p.marca  = m.id
        INNER JOIN categorias c ON p.catego = c.id
        WHERE   p.marca LIKE '%".$q."%'
                OR p.catego LIKE '%".$q."%'
                OR p.pais LIKE '%".$q."%'
        ";
}

$buscarAlumnos=$conexion->query($query);
if ($buscarAlumnos->num_rows > 0)
{
    $tabla.=
    '<table class="table">
        <tr class="bg-primary">
                               <td>id</td>
                           <td>descri</td>
                           <td>precio</td>
                           <td>marca</td>
                           <td>catego</td>
                           <td>pais</td>
                           <td>imagen</td>
        </tr>';




    while($filaAlumnos= $buscarAlumnos->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $tabla.=
        '<tr>
            <td>'.$filaAlumnos['id'].'</td>
            <td>'.utf8_encode($filaAlumnos['descri']).'</td>
            <td>'.$filaAlumnos['precio'].'</td>
            <td>'.$filaAlumnos['nombre_m'].'</td>
            <td>'.$filaAlumnos['nombre_c'].'</td>
            <td>'.$filaAlumnos['pais'].'</td>
            <td>'.$filaAlumnos['imagen'].'</td>
         </tr>
        ';
    }

    $tabla.='</table>';
} else
    {
        $tabla="No se encontraron coincidencias con sus criterios de búsqueda.";
    }


echo $tabla;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta hacer el `JOIN` entre `productos` y `marcas` y en consecuencia incluir la columna de `marcas` que te interesa.

Por ejemplo (me permito identarla para más claridad):

```
$query="
        SELECT 
            p.id, 
            p.descri, 
            p.precio, 
            m.nombre_m, 
            p.catego, 
            p.pais, 
            p.imagen 
        FROM productos p
        INNER JOIN marcas m ON p.marca = m.id
        WHERE   p.marca LIKE '%".$q."%' 
                OR p.catego LIKE '%".$q."%' 
                OR p.pais LIKE '%".$q."%'
        ";
```

O sea, tienes que seleccionar la columna `nombre_m` de `marcas`. He usado alias cortos para cada tabla por simplicidad.

Luego en la lectura de datos:

```
while($filaAlumnos= $buscarAlumnos->fetch_assoc())
{
    $tabla.=
    '<tr>
        <td>'.$filaAlumnos['id'].'</td>
        <td>'.utf8_encode($filaAlumnos['descri']).'</td>
        <td>'.$filaAlumnos['precio'].'</td>
        <td>'.$filaAlumnos['nombre_m'].'</td>
        <td>'.$filaAlumnos['catego'].'</td>
        <td>'.$filaAlumnos['pais'].'</td>
        <td>'.$filaAlumnos['imagen'].'</td>
     </tr>
    ';
}
```

Y, si quieres incluir la tabla `categorias` en el `JOIN`, sería algo así:

```
$query="
        SELECT 
            p.id, 
            p.descri, 
            p.precio, 
            m.nombre_m, 
            c.nombre_c, 
            p.pais, 
            p.imagen 
        FROM productos p
        INNER JOIN marcas m     ON p.marca  = m.id
        INNER JOIN categorias c ON p.catego = c.id
        WHERE   p.marca LIKE '%".$q."%' 
                OR p.catego LIKE '%".$q."%' 
                OR p.pais LIKE '%".$q."%'
        ";
```

Y dentro del `while` lo mismo, buscar la columna `nombre_c`:

```
while($filaAlumnos= $buscarAlumnos->fetch_assoc())
{
    $tabla.=
    '<tr>
        <td>'.$filaAlumnos['id'].'</td>
        <td>'.utf8_encode($filaAlumnos['descri']).'</td>
        <td>'.$filaAlumnos['precio'].'</td>
        <td>'.$filaAlumnos['nombre_m'].'</td>
        <td>'.$filaAlumnos['nombre_c'].'</td>
        <td>'.$filaAlumnos['pais'].'</td>
        <td>'.$filaAlumnos['imagen'].'</td>
     </tr>
    ';
}
```

---

> ### Nota sobre la seguridad
>
> Tu consulta es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*.
>   Considera usar **consultas preparadas** para prevenir ese grave
>   riesgo.

Comment: Buenas, me sigue saltando el mismo error en esa fila
"<td>'.$filaAlumnos['nombre_m'].'</td>"

Comment: @Andres90tl compara la consulta con mi respuesta como esta ahora. Al inicio de la respuesta no me fijé que faltaba el `JOIN`. Y si salta algún error, dime qué error es.

Comment: Pasa lo mismo, supongo que falla la consulta. Yo en otra página utilizaba esta consulta y servía  
`` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` 
 $sql =  "SELECT  productos.id,
            productos.descri,
            productos.precio,
            marcas.nombre_m,
            categorias.nombre_c,
            productos.pais,
            productos.imagen
    FROM marcas
    JOIN productos ON marcas.id = productos.marca
    JOIN categorias ON categorias.id = productos.catego";
`` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` ` 
Pero al intentar agregarla a esta deja de servirme (o la agrego mal)

Comment: @Andres90tl edita tu pregunta poniendo al final la consulta como la tienes ahora. Muestra también el nuevo `while`. Y di qué error da si da error o qué es lo que ocurre.

Comment: Pronto. Supongo que lo tengo bien. ¿Quizá cambiar la forma de la consulta?

Comment: Intenta poner un `var_dump($filaAlumnos);` dentro del `while` y dime lo que muestra por pantalla, para revisar. Y, verifica que la tabla se llame efectivamente `categorias`, @Andres90tl  y la columna de esa tabla `nombre_c`  y el ID de la misma se llama `id`.  Puede que haya un error en los nombres.

Comment: Me vas a querer matar pero... ¿Cómo sería la sintaxis de eso?

Comment: @Andres90tl  dentro del `while`, algo así: `while($filaAlumnos= $buscarAlumnos->fetch_assoc())
{  var_dump($filaAlumnos); /*luego sigue lo demás dentro de ese bloque del while* }` es para probar si hay datos en la consulta y qué datos. Te va a sacar seguro muchas cosas, pero con un bloque de `var_dump` que muestres basta para revisar.

Comment: array (size=7)
  'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'descri' => string 'Lente de zoom de alta velocidad y resoluci�n y gran apertura ZEISS Vario-SonnarT*F2,4-4 de  funci�n de eliminar ruidos. Respuesta de enfoque autom�tico de 0,03 s1.' (length=296)
  'precio' => string '$66650' (length=6)
  'marca' => string '1' (length=1)
  'catego' => string '2' (length=1)
  'pais' => string 'China' (length=5)
  'imagen' => string '../4.imagenes/Sony-Cybershot-DSC-RX10-IV.jpg' (length=44)

Comment: @Andres90tl el resultado del `var_dump` muestra que se está ejecutando la query vieja. Observa que aparece la columna `marca` y la columna `catego` en el resultado: **`'marca' => string '1' (length=1) 'catego' => string '2' (length=1)`**. Relmente no se está ejecutando la nueva query. No sé si es que has omitido algo o es que tienes en memoria caché el código viejo. Revisa de nuevo, sobre todo verifica qué `$query` envías y si no la sobre-escribes (supongo que borraste la variable `$query` vieja).

Comment: No omití nada, puse exactamente lo que me dijiste. Este error me pasaba en otra página (la otra no tenía un buscador en tiempo real) y se solucionó usando una consulta escrita de forma distinta, el tema es que yo no sé hacerlo. Llevo 6h dando vueltas con este problema y ya me fallan las fuerzas :/ solo le pido a Dios una solución :ccccccc

Comment: @Andres90tl La solución ya está, pero tienes que ver por qué la nueva consulta no la está cogiendo. Si quieres edita la pregunta poniendo el código entero como lo tienes ahora para revisarlo.

Comment: Pronto, está en "Actual completo".

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105495/discussion-between-andres90tl-and-a-cedano).